# Add families annotation to ggtree next to geom_bar in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot, ggtree

I would need help in order to add information within a plot.

Here is the plot :

[image]

(Code to get this plot below)

And I would like to add a new element with families information stored in this **tab**:

```
   labels     family
1      t2  Hominidae
2      t4  Hominidae
3      t3  Hominidae
4     t10    Equidae
5      t5    Equidae
6      t7  Muridae
7      t6    Muridae
8      t1 Crisetidae
9      t8 Crisetidae
10     t9   Outgroup
```

**(dput format)**

```
structure(list(labels = c("t2", "t4", "t3", "t10", "t5", "t7", 
"t6", "t1", "t8", "t9"), family = c("Hominidae", "Hominidae", 
"Hominidae", "Equidae", "Equidae", "Murinidae", "Muridae", "Crisetidae", 
"Crisetidae", "Outgroup")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

And get a new figure such as ;

[image]

As you can see, I sued the information stored in the **tab** to add vertical bars followed by the name of the `family` for each `labels`.

### I found this post related (`http://www.randigriffin.com/2017/05/11/primate-phylogeny-ggtree.html`) , but it does not do it with geom_bars, it simply add the family annotations next to tree label...

```
   library(ggplot2)
library(ggtree)

set.seed(2019-10-31)
tr <- rtree(10)

d1 <- data.frame(
  # only some labels match
  label = c(tr$tip.label[sample(9, 9)], "A"),
  value = sample(1:10, 10))

d2 <- data.frame(
  label = rep(tr$tip.label, 5),
  category = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each=10),
  value = rnorm(50, 0, 3)) 

g <- ggtree(tr) + geom_tiplab(align=TRUE) + hexpand(.01)

d2$label <- factor(d2$label, levels = rev(get_taxa_name(g)))
d1$label <- factor(d1$label, levels = rev(get_taxa_name(g)))

p1 <- ggplot(d1, aes(label, value)) + geom_col(aes(fill=label)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=label, y= value+.1)) +
  coord_flip() + theme_tree2() + theme(legend.position='none')

p2 <- ggplot(d2, aes(x=category, y=label)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value)) + scale_fill_viridis_c() + 
  theme_minimal() + xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL)+ theme(legend.position='none')


cowplot::plot_grid(g, p2, p1, ncol=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `left_join` and facets:

```r
d1 <- dplyr::left_join(d1, tab, by = c(label = "labels"))

p1 <- ggplot(d1, aes(label, value)) + geom_col(aes(fill=label)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=label, y= value+.1)) +
  coord_flip() + theme_tree2() + theme(legend.position='none') +
  facet_grid(family~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0), position = "top") +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 0),
        axis.line.y.right = element_line(size = 3),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside")

p2 <- ggplot(d2, aes(x=category, y=label)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  xlab(NULL) + 
  ylab(NULL)+ 
  theme(legend.position='none')


cowplot::plot_grid(g, p2, p1, ncol=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for that ! Do you have any idea how to rotate the facet when the size of the vertical bars is too small so as not to crop the label of the facet family?

Comment: @chippycentra it should be `theme(strip.text = element_text(angle = 90))`